# How can I use standard latex font (computer modern) in a web page?

Tags: fonts, html

Is there an easy way to display webpages in computer modern font?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not about TeX, but rather about web page design. Voting to close.

Comment: I wouldn't close since this is relevant e.g. for LaTeX2HTML when you want to have a similar look.

Comment: If you google for Computer modern webfont, a few results like http://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/ come back

Comment: @Sverre This question helps to find answers on how to make web pages look like latex, so it's not unrelated to latex.

Comment: @user3022127 It might not be entirely unrelated. But would you ask a question like "how do I get my MS Word document to look like LaTeX"/"how can I type LaTeX-like math expressions in Word" here or on a MS Word forum?

Comment: @moewe Is it possible to move it to stackoverflow then?

Comment: Mhhh, yes there is some official procedure that can do this. Maybe you need to flag it for the moderators? Or you just go over to Stackoverflow (or some other fitting site) and do it again.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most stable way to do this I found was to base64 a font I found at http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/. I used the cmunrm.otf from there, base64'ed it and put it as a font face in my css.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "my-font";
  src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,T1R...gP5w/kP+RAA format("opentype");
}

body {
  font-family: "my-font";
}
```

You can see an example at https://jsfiddle.net/jtvx9auo/

While you could also simply download the otf file and put it to your server, I found base64ing to be more reliable, e.g. when trying to convert to pdf using wkhtmltopdf.